# How to show image/icon in taskbar context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, trayicon

I'm using Hardcodet NotifyIcon, and I want to display images next to my context menu items. But for some reason they don't appear.

This is the code

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="MyNotifyIcon" Icon="{x:Static p:Resources.frame_01}" ToolTipText="hello world">
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.TraybarTitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>

    <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Background="{StaticResource JITB.SolidColors.Cyan}">
            <MenuItem Click="Menu_Open">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Open" Foreground="White"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="../../Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-open.ico.png"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Click="Menu_Close">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Close" Foreground="White"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="../../Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-close.ico.png"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see - no images!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to put in the Source the absolute path, instead of relative?

Comment: Set the Build Action of the image files to `Resource`, then remove the `../..` part from the paths.

Comment: Try the following path: Source="/Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-open.ico.png">. Or: Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-open.ico.png". Are your images really named ".ico.png"?

Comment: @Mishka You're right - that was the problem... I don't understand it, as intellisense gave me the option to complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a pack URI:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-open.ico.png" />
```

Or an absolute path:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Resources/Icons/Tray-menu-icons-open.ico.png" />
```

Also make sure that the `Build Action` properties of the images have been set to "Resource" and that the path and file name is correct.

Comment: Where the `pack://application:,,,` prefix isn't actually necessary in XAML, because it is added automatically. So the "absolute path" is implicitly also an assembly Resource File Pack URI.